# conditionally implement trait inside macro invocation

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming, traits

I'm looking to create a macro to generate thin wrappers for some basic types, for example, the syntax:

```rust
wrapper!(String => Email);
```

would expand to something roughly like:

```rust
struct Email {
  inner: String,
}

impl Email {
  // some boilerplate-y stuff
}
```

However, I'd like these types to implement some stdlib traits where appropriate (e.g. `Eq`, `Clone`, `Copy`, etc. In particular, `Copy` is causing problems here.

I'd like the wrapper type to be `Copy` if the inner type is `Copy` (similar to how `#[derive]` works), however if I put a derive implementation on the generated trait, I get an error if incompatible:

```rust
macro_rules! wrapper {
  ($inner:ty => $name:ident) => {
    #[derive(Copy)] 
    struct $name {
      inner: $inner
    }
  }
}

wrapper!(i64 => Version);  // works fine
wrapper!(String => Email);  // Error, String is not Copy
```

Instead of a compile-time error when using a non-copy type, I'd rather it just "didn't try to implement `Copy`", but I'm not sure how to express that in macros.

Another unsuccessful attempt looked like:

```rust
// inside macro
impl Copy for $name where $inner: Copy {}
```

But this gave me the same `String is not Copy` error. I would have hoped that, during expansion, when it hits: `impl Copy for Email where String: Copy` it would realise: "`String: Copy` is not satisfied, so this implementation is not valid" and move on, but instead it just errors.

Is there any way to have a macro expand into different code based on trait implementations?

Comment: There was a tweet about a macro that did something similar. I can not find it however hard I search. It was something like: "splitting the compiler with rust proc macros" and a picture of some code. That probably uses something helpful.

Comment: Here it is: https://crates.io/crates/whichever-compiles

Comment: Ah thanks, interesting to know you can `fork()` in a macro, but probably not something for downstream consumers, thanks anyways :-D

Comment: You can trick the compiler with generics: `#[derive(Clone, Copy)] struct Email<T = String> { inner: T }`. This is interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *trivial bounds*. This had [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2056-allow-trivial-where-clause-constraints.md), but it was only partially applied. I'm not sure why (neither the RFC nor the tracking issue nor the implementation PR mention a reason).

On nightly, you can do that by turning on the `trivial_bounds` feature ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f6bc693fe4445c2a0387d7ef9fa4b8c)).

If you are forced to stable, you can use the following ugly trick from [this comment](https://github.com/taiki-e/pin-project/issues/102#issuecomment-540472282):

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Wrapper<'a, T> {
    pub inner: T,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

macro_rules! wrapper {
    ($inner:ty => $name:ident) => {
        struct $name {
            inner: Wrapper<'static, $inner>,
        }
        impl Copy for $name where for<'a> Wrapper<'a, $inner>: Copy {}
        impl Clone for $name
        where
            for<'a> Wrapper<'a, $inner>: Clone,
        {
            fn clone(&self) -> Self {
                Self {
                    inner: self.inner.clone(),
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3f27002fe0522c5bb79426484df1aeb).

The lifetime tricks Rust to think this is a generic struct that it can't check whether it implements `Copy`.